# Importing data from Access Table in runtime

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I import data from an Access database just fine. However, I want to make the DB a runtime (.accdr instead of .accde). The Runtime works fine, too, on its own, but I cannot import data from a runtime application when in Excel (it does not permit it).

How can I contact my database and have a Runtime mode?

Nothing on the web I have found even mentions this problem. I have no problem with opening an ADODB connection with VBA if it is required.

Comment: @HansUp I can't import my database data when doing it from within Excel.

Comment: What Excel method are you attempting to use to import the Access data?

Comment: The simple Data > From Access, select a table and click where you want it to be.

Comment: OK. Then is the problem that your *.accdr database file is not displayed among the data source choices?

Comment: Got it!  I was confused because you said Excel won't permit it ... which made me think Excel complained somehow when you tried.  Since an ACCDR is not available via *Data>From Access*, you can open a recordset and then use Excel's [Range.CopyFromRecordset Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ACCDR databases are not displayed among the choices offered by Excel's *Data>From Access* option, you can open a recordset to retrieve your Access data and then use Excel's [CopyFromRecordset Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx) to save those data into a worksheet.

This code uses a DAO recordset loaded from an ACCDR database file and saves the data in the active worksheet ...

```vb
Const cstrDbPath As String = "C:\share\Access\Database2.accdr"
Const cstrDao = "DAO.DBEngine.120"
Dim dbe As Object ' DAO.DBEngine
Dim db As Object ' DAO.Database
Dim rs As Object ' DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "SELECT 'Hello World' AS greet_world;"
Set dbe = CreateObject(cstrDao)
Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase(cstrDbPath, True)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
db.Close
```

That code uses DAO with late binding.  If you prefer early binding, add *"Microsoft Office <version> Access database engine Object Library"* to your project's references.

Or if you prefer ADO, `CopyFromRecordset` will also work with an ADO recordset.

Comment: What are the advantages of early binding vs late binding?

Comment: Early binding allows you to take advantage of Intellisense, which can be useful during development.  And theoretically it should offer better performance, but I doubt you would notice any difference here.  Late binding avoids deployment issues because no reference is required so the code will not break when the expected version is not available.